# Change Notification Balloon Size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-10

I have here a windows forms application using `NotifyIcon`

Everything works perfectly fine in Win 7 environment, until Win10 came...

The content of my notification balloon has 9 lines.

But when I run my app in Win10, some lines of the notification content are not shown in the balloon.

How can I resize the balloon in Win10?

**[Correct] Win 7 notification:**

[image]

**[Not Good] Meanwhile in Win 10:**

[image]

[UPDATE] Notification balloon won't show in 64-bit os.

Comment: Does this also happen in Windows 8.x?

Comment: @MatthewWatson The notifications center is new to Win10.

Comment: I suspect it may not be possible. Microsoft have shifted in recent years away from "Developers can be trusted not to abuse feature X and annoy users" - based, unfortunately, on ample evidence. Which means that they don't give us much control over things that steal a users attention (i.e. imagine if you wanted to create a balloon so big it occupied the entire screen) I'd suggest putting less information in the balloon (maybe just how many files have transferred? if its some kind of transfer program) and let the balloon click action bring up a real dialog showing more details, if the user wants

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible without hacking, but if you want to some examples on doing this are written here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37912/Embedding-NET-Controls-to-NotifyIcon-Balloon-Toolt

I would advice you, if this is even possible, to move to WPF (or use a mix). For WPF there is a component which allows you to use custom popups. All the information on this can be found here: http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon